# TypeError: sportCategory() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, typeerror

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, 
jsonify
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, SportCategory, MenuItem

app = Flask(__name__)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sportmenu.db',connect_args= 
{'check_same_thread':False},)
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/catalog/')
def sportCategory(id):
sport = 
session.query(SportCategory).order_by(SportCategory.name).filter_by(id 
= category_id)
items = 
session.query(MenuItem).order_by(MenuItem.date.desc()).filter_by(id = 
menu_item_id)
return render_template('menu.html',category = sport, items = items)
```

The code above will not run. I have tried mostly everything within my knowledge. What might be wrong with it?

Here is what the code above is referring too.

```
class SportCategory(Base):
__tablename__ = 'category'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)


class MenuItem(Base):
__tablename__ = 'menu_item'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
description = Column(String(1000))
price = Column(String(8))
date = Column(Integer)
sport_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
sport = relationship(SportCategory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by these three lines.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/catalog/')
def sportCategory(id):
```

The first two declare routes with no variables. But the `def` declares a route handler that expects one. The simple fix is to change the first two to

```
@app.route('/<id>')
@app.route('/catalog/<id>')
```

And you might want to supply a separate

```
@app.route('/')
def noSportCategory():
```

to handle the case of no id.